# How to obtain "normalized" model residuals for Generalized Estimating Equations?

Tags: lme4-nlme, residuals, covariance-matrix, standardization, generalized-estimating-equations

How does one compute the "normalized" model residuals based via geepack's geeglm/gee in R?

The nlme package in R allows one to compute the

**normalized model residuals:**

> (standardized residuals pre-multiplied by the inverse square-root factor of the estimated error correlation matrix)

GLS takes into account an non-compound-symmetry covariance-correlation matrix of the errors, or some ARMA process in the series.

GEE uses non-compound-symmetry non-OLS induced covariance/correlation structures, so we need to compute the normalized residuals, because they're more informative than regular residuals as we're not using compound-symmetry, because the "inverse-square root factor" isn't constant, so how does one program GEE to give us the "normalized model residuals" as nlme does? We cannot rely on huber-white's advantages as we don't always have enough data.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/nlme.pdf

Comment: Not really answering your question, but see related discussions here https://github.com/florianhartig/DHARMa/issues/339

Comment: @FlorianHartig Is it already interpretable to look at a GEE model residual versus fitted plot minus the fact they are not normalized, so no need for transformations into a different coordinate system?

Comment: You can do this, but the question is how to interpret it. The very point of GEE is that they will be more robust against certain residual problems. So, when fitting an OLS or GEE to some data, you might get the same residual pattern, but you should possibly be less concerned in a GEE because it should be more robust to such patterns. How to quantify this exactly, however, I have no idea, you have to check the literature on GEEs.